# When to use "after yourself" & When to use "after you" in the structure "tidy up after somebody"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, reflexive-pronouns

See [this structure](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/tidy) in the dictionary.

**tidy up after somebody**:

Eg: *I’m tired of tidying up after **you** boys* (=tidying somewhere that someone else has made untidy).

Eg: *When you cook, could you please tidy up after **yourself**.*

When to use "**after yourself / himself / herself...**" & When to use "**after you / him / her" in the structure**" tidy up after somebody"?

Here is what I think but I am not sure I am right, if the subject & the object after "after" are the same then the object should be "*yourself / himself / herself...*"

*He often tidies up after himself*

*She often tidies up after herself*

*We often tidy up after ourselves*

But if the subject & the object after "after" are not the same then the object should be "*you / him / her...*"

*We have to tidy up after him*

*I have to tidy up after him*

but not sure which one is correct "*I have to tidy up after ourselves*" or "*I have to tidy up after us*"

& not sure which one is correct, Eg: I say "*you have to tidy up after me*" or "*you have to tidy up after myself*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *reflexive pronouns* in English are:

- **myself**     *first person singular*
- **yourself**      *second person singular*
- **himself**      *third person singular*
- **herself**      *third person singular*
- **itself**      *third person singular*
- **ourselves**      *first person plural*
- **yourselves**      *second person plural*
- **themselves**      *third person plural*

We use the *reflexive pronoun* as the direct object only when it agrees in both person and number with the subject of the verb, as in the example from Longmans:

> "...could **you**<sup><sup><sup>2nd Sing.</sup>SUBJECT</sup></sup> please [tidy up after]<sup><sup>VERB</sup></sup> **yourself**<sup><sup><sup>2nd Sing.</sup>OBJECT</sup></sup>?"

In your example sentence, the first person *singular* pronoun **I** is the subject. We can't use the first person plural reflexive pronoun, because the *singular* subject **I** is not in agreement with the first person *plural* in the object. Instead, we use the objective form of the first person plural pronoun, which is **us**:

> **I**<sup><sup><sup>1st Sing.</sup>SUBJECT</sup></sup> [have to tidy up after]<sup><sup>VERB</sup></sup> <s>ourselves</s> **us**<sup><sup><sup>3rd Pl.</sup>OBJECT</sup></sup>.

Similarly, in your other example, we cannot use the first person singular reflexive pronoun as the object because it does not agree in person and number with the second person singular pronoun in the subject. Instead, we use the objective form of the first person singular pronoun, which is **me**:

> "...**you**<sup><sup><sup>2nd Person</sup> SUBJECT</sup></sup> [have to tidy up after]<sup><sup>VERB</sup></sup> <s>myself</s> **me**<sup><sup><sup>1st Sing.</sup>OBJECT</sup></sup>."